# How to display the instruction instantly when response is coming?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a chatgpt-like website using openai API for gpt. but gpt is taking few seconds to generate the response and because of that my code is only displaying the instruction when gpt is generated the response but i want to instantly display that instruction on screen as user typed the instruction in the text input like as ChatGpt

So how can i do that with my code where there will be multiple conventions? what is the best way to do that? In my code the "outputText" is the text generated by chatgpt.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TextInput({ label, ...props }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                {...props}
                value={props.instruction}
                onChange={props.handleInstructionChange}
                placeholder=""
            />
            <button onClick={props.Startchat}>Send Message</button>
            <label htmlFor={props.id}>{label}</label>
        </div>
    );
}

const Chat = () => {
    const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([{ instruction: '', outputText: '' }]);
    const [instruction, setInstruction] = useState('');

    const handleInstructionChange = (event) => {
        setInstruction(event.target.value);
    };

    const Startchat = async () => {
        try {
            const outputText = "Hello, I am chatgpt"

            setConversation([...conversation, { instruction, outputText }]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
            {conversation.map((message, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                    {message.instruction.length > 0 && (
                        <div>
                            {message.instruction}
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {message.outputText.length > 0 && (
                        <div>
                            {message.outputText}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            ))}
            <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                <TextInput
                    label="."
                    name="."
                    autoComplete="text"
                    required
                    Startchat={Startchat}
                    handleInstructionChange={handleInstructionChange}
                    instruction={instruction}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create **ID** field in conversations

> const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([{id:0, instruction: '', outputText: '' }]);

Now change your *Startchat* function

1. create unique id at first [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

> import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
>
> const uniqueId = uuidv4()

2. add new conversation into state with above **id**

> setConversation([...conversation, {id:uniqueId, instruction, outputText:"" }]);

3. now fetch the output from **ChatGPT**
4. update output in the conversation state using uniqueId

Your **Startchat** function would be like this

```
const Startchat = async () => {
  try {
    // generate unique ID
    const uniqueId = uuidv4();

    // set instruction in state & mapped with uniqueId
    setConversation((prevConv) => [...prevConv, {id:uniqueId, instruction, outputText:"" }]);
    
    // fetch output text from chatGPT
    const outputText = "Hello, I am chatgpt";

    // set outputText in state on the above uniqueId
    setConversation((prevConv) => {
      const elementIndex = prevConv.findIndex((c) => c.id == uniqueId);
      prevConv[elementIndex] = {
        ...prevConv[elementIndex],
        outputText
      }
      return prevConv
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```